# Install cgconfig in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, cgroup

I want to create some control groups using `cgroup`.

So far I have done the following:

1. I installed some packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cgroup-bin cgroup-lite cgroup-tools cgroupfs-mount libcgroup1
   ```
2. Then I created the `/etc/cgconfig.conf` file with the following content:

   ```
   mount {
     cpuset  = /cgroup/cpuset;
     cpu     = /cgroup/cpu;
     cpuacct = /cgroup/cpuacct;
     memory  = /cgroup/memory;
     devices = /cgroup/devices;
     freezer = /cgroup/freezer;
     net_cls = /cgroup/net_cls;
     ns      = /cgroup/ns;
     blkio   = /cgroup/blkio;
   }

   group limitcpu{
     cpu {
       cpu.shares = 400;
     }
   }

   group limitmem{
     memory {
       memory.limit_in_bytes = 512m;
     }
   }

   group limitio{
     blkio {
       blkio.throttle.read_bps_device = "252:0         2097152";
     }
   }

   group browsers{
     cpu {
       cpu.shares = 200;
     }
     memory {
       memory.limit_in_bytes = 128m;
     }
   }
   ```

   according to the guide [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-limit-resources-using-cgroups-on-centos-6), assuming, that the config file resides at the same location and uses the same syntax on Ubuntu, as it uses on CentOS.
3. Then according to that guide I need to start the `cgconfig service`. I tried with:

   ```
   sudo service cgconfig restart
   ```

   But, oh no! A file is missing!:

   ```
   Failed to restart cgconfig.service: Unit cgconfig.service not found.
   ```
4. After some wondering and searching around, I tried:

   ```
   ● cgconfig.service
      Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
      Active: inactive (dead)
   ```

So it seems I am simply not having any cgconfig service on my system!

I searched for it using:

```
sudo aptitude search cgconfig
```

However, no `cgconfig` is to be found.

How can I install `cgconfig` on my Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 15):

OK, I managed myself to do the same you did, but with some changes:

1) I installed the same utilities:

```
sudo apt-get install cgroup-bin cgroup-lite cgroup-tools cgroupfs-mount libcgroup1
```

2) I edited conf files like this:

`/etc/init/cgroup-lite.conf`

```
description "mount available cgroup filesystems"
author "Serge Hallyn <serge.hallyn@canonical.com>"

start on mounted MOUNTPOINT=/sys/fs/cgroup

pre-start script
test -x /bin/cgroups-mount || { stop; exit 0; }
test -d /sys/fs/cgroup || { stop; exit 0; }
/bin/cgroups-mount
cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf
end script

post-stop script
if [ -x /bin/cgroups-umount ]
then
    /bin/cgroups-umount
fi
end script
```

`/etc/cgconfig.conf`

```
# Since systemd is working well, this section may not be necessary.
# Uncomment if you need it
#
# mount {
# cpuacct = /cgroup/cpuacct;
# memory = /cgroup/memory;
# devices = /cgroup/devices;
# freezer = /cgroup/freezer;
# net_cls = /cgroup/net_cls;
# blkio = /cgroup/blkio;
# cpuset = /cgroup/cpuset;
# cpu = /cgroup/cpu;
# }

group limitcpu{
  cpu {
    cpu.shares = 400;
  }
}

group limitmem{
  memory {
    memory.limit_in_bytes = 512m;
  }
}

group limitio{
  blkio {
    blkio.throttle.read_bps_device = "252:0         2097152";
  }
}

group browsers {
    cpu {
#       Set the relative share of CPU resources equal to 25%
    cpu.shares = "256";
}
memory {
#       Allocate at most 512M of memory to tasks
        memory.limit_in_bytes = "512m";
#       Apply a soft limit of 512 MB to tasks
        memory.soft_limit_in_bytes = "384m";
    }
}

group media-players {
    cpu {
#       Set the relative share of CPU resources equal to 25%
        cpu.shares = "256";
    }
    memory {
#       Allocate at most 256M of memory to tasks
        memory.limit_in_bytes = "256m";
#       Apply a soft limit of 196 MB to tasks
        memory.soft_limit_in_bytes = "128m";
    }
}

cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf
```

And `/etc/cgrules.conf`

```
user:process                                         subsystems   group
[user]:/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser   cpu,memory      browsers
[user]:/usr/bin/clementine                        cpu,memory     media-players
```

That is an example, use your username instead of [user]. You can add the applications you need to limit and define whether you want them to be CPU-, memory- or both limited.

I edited the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
```

Updating it:

```
sudo update-grub
```

3) And finally rebooting to apply changes.

And that is how I've got this working. Before this I was having frequent OOMs with multitasking - with chromium-browser, clementine, sublime-text and other applications using a lot of resources -, now they are running smoothly and I can multitask better.

I really hope this may help others.

Currently using *Ubuntu 16.04 LTS* with *Intel Dual Core 2.6 Ghz* and *4 Gb.* RAM.

Comment: This feels like the right approach, but instead of using cgrules.conf, I find cgexec to be better.  Also, I think you meant to name the file `cgconfig.conf` and not `cgconf.conf`.  If systemd is doing its job, I don't think you need the `mount` section in this file.

Comment: I edited this reply following Mark's recommendation, tested it and works well.

Comment: @Mark, I would be interested in your solution with `cgexec`.

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same issue. It looks like there is no built-in service in current Ubuntu distributions to load cgroup config files.

You will find some (broken?) example init scripts at 
**/usr/share/doc/cgroup-tools/examples/cgconfig** and
**/usr/share/doc/cgroup-tools/examples/cgred**.

To manually load the config files you can use

```
# Loads /etc/cgconfig.conf 
cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf

# Loads /etc/cgrules.conf
cgrulesengd -vvv --logfile=/var/log/cgrulesengd.log
```

As a poor man's solution I wrote myself an init script that loads both files on system startup.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          cgconf
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start:
# Should-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Configures CGroups
### END INIT INFO

start_service() {
  if is_running; then
    echo "cgrulesengd is running already!"
    return 1
  else
    echo "Processing /etc/cgconfig.conf..."
    cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf
    echo "Processing /etc/cgrules.conf..."
    cgrulesengd -vvv --logfile=/var/log/cgrulesengd.log
    return 0
  fi
}

stop_service() {
  if is_running; then
    echo "Stopping cgrulesengd..."
    pkill cgrulesengd
  else
    echo "cgrulesengd is not running!"
    return 1
  fi
}

status() {
  if pgrep cgrulesengd > /dev/null; then
    echo "cgrulesengd is running"
    return 0
  else
    echo "cgrulesengd is not running!"
    return 3
  fi
}

is_running() {
  status >/dev/null 2>&1
}

case "${1:-}" in
  start)
    start_service
    ;;
  stop)
    stop_service
    ;;
  status)
    status
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/cgconf {start|stop|restart|status}"
    exit 2
    ;;
esac

exit $?
```

Save this file at **/etc/init.d/cgconf** and install it using

```
# make the script executable
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/cgconf

# register the service
update-rc.d cgconf defaults

# start the service
service cgconf start

# check the status
service cgconf status
```