# How can I configure CGroups and limit Chrome memory usage on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, cgroup

I am going through https://gist.github.com/juanje/9861623. I am trying to limit my `Chromes` memory usage on my Ubuntu 18.04. It appears my system don't have any of the mentioned commands/files [here](https://gist.github.com/juanje/9861623). What would be a proper way to configure `cgroup` on my Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: The following link proposes a solution for 16.04 : [Loading cgroup config files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836469/install-cgconfig-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 2):

First, you should ensure that you have kernel 4.5 or higher. Actually, most things will work with 4.11 or higher. 
 $  uname -a

This is because you most likely have cgroup v2 , not v1, which has different configuration. Most of the links for ubuntu 16.04 and others, refer to v1. Don't get confused.

If your run "mount -t cgroup" , you should see a list of cgroups, all under /sys/fs/cgroup .

Now, the configurations starts with :
  $ cp /usr/share/doc/cgroup-tools/examples/cgred.conf /etc/

Then, the rest are very similar to :
[Install cgconfig in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836469/install-cgconfig-in-ubuntu-16-04)

All info about the new case (18.04) be found in : 
https://www.paranoids.at/cgroup-ubuntu-18-04-howto/

The test in my case, showed my new /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/browsers/ and tasks.

Good luck.

Comment: Many thanks @MiGrieves! let me try this solution :)