# Is it possible to patch without spiking the CPU?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, swap, cpu-load, unattended-upgrades

I'm using unattended upgrades to patch about 300 ubuntu (16.04 LTS) machines (network appliances really), some are 1 CPU VMs running on ESXi, azure and AWS and others bare-metal quad core Atom IOT devices.  I haven't experienced this issues on the bare-metal machines, but on the VM's, which are powered just enough to do what they need to do, when the machines patch themselves our SNMP monitoring goes nuts and we get high CPU spikes, swap memory alerts, etc..

Rather than work in ways to suppress these alerts (which is not what I'm asking about), are there any ways to let renice patching and just let it take its time patching?   I wouldn't mind if it took 4 hours to patch, unattended that is (I wouldn't want to have patching go that slowly if I kicked it off with ansible or apt directly).

Answer (score 3):

I think this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/899273/307523) contains everything you are looking for:

> OK, I managed myself to do the same you did, but with some changes:

1) I installed the same utilities:

```
sudo apt-get install cgroup-bin cgroup-lite cgroup-tools cgroupfs-mount libcgroup1
```

2) I edited conf files like this:

`sudo -H gedit /etc/init/cgroup-lite.conf`

```
description "mount available cgroup filesystems"
author "Serge Hallyn <serge.hallyn@canonical.com>"

start on mounted MOUNTPOINT=/sys/fs/cgroup

pre-start script
test -x /bin/cgroups-mount || { stop; exit 0; }
test -d /sys/fs/cgroup || { stop; exit 0; }
/bin/cgroups-mount
cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf
end script

post-stop script
if [ -x /bin/cgroups-umount ]
then
    /bin/cgroups-umount
fi
end script
```

`sudo -H gedit /etc/cgconfig.conf`

```
# Since systemd is working well, this section may not be necessary.
# Uncomment if you need it
#
# mount {
# cpuacct = /cgroup/cpuacct;
# memory = /cgroup/memory;
# devices = /cgroup/devices;
# freezer = /cgroup/freezer;
# net_cls = /cgroup/net_cls;
# blkio = /cgroup/blkio;
# cpuset = /cgroup/cpuset;
# cpu = /cgroup/cpu;
# }

group limitcpu{
  cpu {
    cpu.shares = 400;
  }
}

group limitmem{
  memory {
    memory.limit_in_bytes = 512m;
  }
}

group limitio{
  blkio {
    blkio.throttle.read_bps_device = "252:0         2097152";
  }
}

group browsers {
    cpu {
#       Set the relative share of CPU resources equal to 25%
    cpu.shares = "256";
}
memory {
#       Allocate at most 512M of memory to tasks
        memory.limit_in_bytes = "512m";
#       Apply a soft limit of 512 MB to tasks
        memory.soft_limit_in_bytes = "384m";
    }
}

group media-players {
    cpu {
#       Set the relative share of CPU resources equal to 25%
        cpu.shares = "256";
    }
    memory {
#       Allocate at most 256M of memory to tasks
        memory.limit_in_bytes = "256m";
#       Apply a soft limit of 196 MB to tasks
        memory.soft_limit_in_bytes = "128m";
    }
}

cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf
```

`sudo -H gedit /etc/cgrules.conf`

```
user:process                                         subsystems   group
[user]:/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser   cpu,memory      browsers
[user]:/usr/bin/clementine                        cpu,memory     media-players
```

**Note: This section needs to be updated with `/usr/bin/apt`**

That is an example, use your username instead of [user]. You can add the applications you need to limit and define whether you want them to be CPU-, memory- or both limited.

I edited the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
```

Updating it:

```
sudo update-grub
```

3) And finally rebooting to apply changes.

> And that is how I've got this working. Before this I was having
>   frequent OOMs with multitasking - with chromium-browser, clementine,
>   sublime-text and other applications using a lot of resources -, now
>   they are running smoothly and I can multitask better.

---

Additional `cgroups` resources:

- `cgroups` was developed by Google in 2006: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups)
- [Everything You Need to Know about Linux Containers, Part I: Linux Control Groups and Process Isolation](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/everything-you-need-know-about-linux-containers-part-i-linux-control-groups-and-process)